# retrieve multidiensional array keys without infinitely nested foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

let's say I have a really complicated multidimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
        [A] => Array
            (
                [B] => Array
                    (
                        [C] => Array
                            (
                                [D] => Array
                                    (
                                        [E] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [id] =>
                                                        [firstname] =>
                                                        [lastname] => 
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

In this array, the number of keys can vary depending on the situation, for example, the keys could be only A, B and C, or only A and B, or even A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, ... etc. Is it possible to gather the keys (the inner keys A, B, C, D and E in this case) of such array without having 20 nested foreach loops?

Thank you

Comment: Try recursion! just a sec and I will bring code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to recursively enumerate the keys? Here's a function to do that:

```
function enumerateKeys($array, &$keys) {
    if(!isset($keys)) {
        $keys = array();
    }

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $keys[] = $key; /* Moved below if() to enumerate only array keys */
            enumerateKeys($value, $keys);
        }
    }
}
```

[Here's a working demo.](http://codepad.org/QBHp8nS8)

Comment: enumerateKeys($array, $keys);, Where's that variable $keys defined in your working demo?

Comment: @user765368: It's not. I pass it by reference, so it doesn't have to be defined (hence the `isset` check in `enumerateKeys`).

Comment: Good, but this also returns the keys inside the deeper non-multidimensional array. I wanted just the keys of the arrays which contains another array (A, B, C, D, E in my case)

Comment: @user765368: Okay, answer edited to reflect that change. (Moved one line! :D)

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, but it's missing one thing, I want the key searches to STOP as soon as I encounter an array in which the first element is NOT an array. In order words, in my example above, I want to stop at key E (so I want A, B, C, D, E). I'll try to make that change to reflect what I want

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice recursive solution for you:

```
function getKeys($yourArray) {
  $allKeys = array();
  if(is_array($yourArray)) {
    foreach($yourArray as $key => $value) {
       $allKeys = array_push($allKeys,$key);
       $allKeys = array_merge($allKeys,getKeys($value));
    }
  } else {
    //this line will also add the values if you want them
    //if you only want keys then just leave it out
    $allKeys = array_push($allKeys,$yourArray);
  }
  return $allKeys;
}
```