# Get new value and keys of multidimensional php array with recursive function

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, nested

How to make follwoing function work for unlimited nested arrays without doing this manually in the way i did it ? (without using foreach nested in another foreach).

This is the array but can be way more nested and has more data:

```
Array
(
    [options] => Array
        (
            [company_details] => Array
                (
                    [contact] => Array
                        (
                            [company_name] => Some Name
                            [email] => info@example.com
                            [phone_mobile] => 043333333
                            [phone_work] => 012222233
                        )

                )

        )

    [another_array] => some_data
)
```

Loop:

```
foreach ($form_data as $key=>$value) { // options/css/etc..      

   $key_1 = $key;
   if (!is_array($value)) {
      $new_value = $form_data[$key_1];
      $array[$key_1] = $new_value;
   }

   if (is_array($value)) {
      foreach ($value as $key=>$value) { // company_details/shop_settings/etc..

         $key_2 = $key;
         if (!is_array($value)) {
            $new_value = $form_data[$key_1][$key_2];
            $array[$key_1][$key_2] = $new_value;
         }

         if (is_array($value)) {

            foreach ($value as $key=>$value) { // contact/social_links/etc..

               $key_3 = $key;
               if (!is_array($value)) {
                  $new_value = $form_data[$key_1][$key_2][$key_3];
                  $array[$key_1][$key_2][$key_3] = $new_value;
               }

               if (is_array($value)) {

                  foreach ($value as $key=>$value) { // email/mobile/etc..
                     
                     $key_4 = $key;
                     if (!is_array($value)) {
                        $new_value = $form_data[$key_1][$key_2][$key_3][$key_4];
                        $array[$key_1][$key_2][$key_3][$key_4] = $new_value;
                     }

                     if (is_array($value)) {

                        foreach ($value as $key=>$value) { // email/mobile/etc..
                           
                           $key_5 = $key;
                           if (!is_array($value)) {
                              $new_value = $form_data[$key_1][$key_2][$key_3][$key_4][$key_5];
                              $array[$key_1][$key_2][$key_3][$key_4][$key_5] = $new_value;
                           }
                        
                        }
                     }
                  
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have tried [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9233845/11001561) ,but the issue is that the array are not stopping at the final key. So instead getting this:

```
function enumerateKeys($array, &$keys) {

   if(!isset($keys)) {
       $keys = array();
   }

   foreach($array as $key => $value) {
       if(is_array($value)) {
           $keys[] = $key; /* Moved below if() to enumerate only array keys */
           enumerateKeys($value, $keys);
       }
   }
   
}

// EXPECTED OUTPUT:
Array
(
    [0] => options
    [1] => company_details
    [2] => contact
    [4] => company_name
)

Array
(
    [0] => options
    [1] => company_details
    [2] => contact
    [4] => email
)

Array
(
    [0] => options
    [1] => company_details
    [2] => contact
    [4] => phone_number
)
```

I am getting this:

```
// WRONG OUTPUT:
Array
(
    [0] => options
    [1] => company_details
    [2] => contact
)

Array
(
    [0] => options
    [1] => company_details
    [2] => contact
)

Array
(
    [0] => options
    [1] => company_details
    [2] => contact
)
```

I have tried to add the final key as well, but then its not getting the indexed key number and its not stopping after the final key, it just add more data to the array which mix everthing together like this:

```
function enumerateKeys($array, &$keys) {

   if(!isset($keys)) {
       $keys = array();
   }

   foreach($array as $key => $value) {
       if(is_array($value)) {
           $keys[] = $key; /* Moved below if() to enumerate only array keys */
           enumerateKeys($value, $keys);
           
       }
       $keys[$key] = $value;
   }
   
  
}

//OUTPUT:

Array
(
    [0] => options
    [1] => company_details
    [2] => contact
    [company_name] => Some Name
)

Array
(
    [0] => options
    [1] => company_details
    [2] => contact
    [company_name] => Some Name
    [email] => info@example.com
)

Array
(
    [0] => options
    [1] => company_details
    [2] => contact
    [company_name] => Some Name
    [email] => info@example.com
    [phone_mobile] => 04333333333
)
```

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: @Barmar I have edited  my question you can find the array on the top of the question

Comment: The other question only wanted the keys of array elements that have nested arrays in them. Take `$keys[] = $key;` out of the `if` to get all keys.

Comment: @Barmar I have moved it above the `if` , but now i am getting 4 equals arrays at the end and each array has all keys. `options|company_details|contact|company_name|email|phone_number|etc..`

Comment: You can use `array_unique()` to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: @Barmar no, array_unique is not helping in this case. it needs to stop when the last value is not an array and continue with the next one. so each time the foreach loop  gets to a non array value it should close the array and open a new array.. like the `// EXPECTED OUTPUT:` in my question

Comment: @Barmar to make it more simple, i need the path of each array e.g path-0 `[options][company_details][contact][company_name]` path-1 `[options][company_details][contact][email]`

Answer (score 0):

You can build a new array and add the elements to it while execution the function recursively.

Code like this would work and return the array structure as expected:

```php
$array = [
    'options' => [
        'company_details' => [
            'contact' => [
                'company_name' => 'Some Name',
                'email' => 'info@example.com',
                'phone_mobile' => 043333333,
                'phone_work' => 012222233
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

function enumerateKeys($array, &$keys = null)
{
    $newArray = [];

    if (!isset($keys)) {
        $keys = [];
    }

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $keys[] = $key; /* Moved below if() to enumerate only array keys */
            return enumerateKeys($value, $keys);
        }
        $keys[] = $key;
        $newArray[] = $keys;
        array_pop($keys);

        if (count($newArray) === count($array, true)) {
            return $newArray;
        }
    }
}

$arrays = enumerateKeys($array);
```

The `$arrays` output is:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'options' (length=7)
      1 => string 'company_details' (length=15)
      2 => string 'contact' (length=7)
      3 => string 'company_name' (length=12)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'options' (length=7)
      1 => string 'company_details' (length=15)
      2 => string 'contact' (length=7)
      3 => string 'email' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'options' (length=7)
      1 => string 'company_details' (length=15)
      2 => string 'contact' (length=7)
      3 => string 'phone_mobile' (length=12)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'options' (length=7)
      1 => string 'company_details' (length=15)
      2 => string 'contact' (length=7)
      3 => string 'phone_work' (length=10)
```

Note: if you want the value of company_name, email, etc. just change the `$keys[] = $key;` right after the if to `$keys[] = $value;`.

Comment: @Nash Is my answer helpful to you?